# how to write date using tokenizer?

Tags: java

The following code here returns the date in the form "Day, Date, Month, Year".
The date currently entered in would return as Saturday 28 Dec 2013. However, I want to tokenize this and print the 4 parts out on 4 separate lines, starting with month, then date, then year, then day. What's the best way to do this?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Day{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

    SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        Date myDate = newDateFormat.parse("28/12/2013");
        newDateFormat.applyPattern("EEEE dd MMM yyyy");
        String isDate = newDateFormat.format(myDate);
        System.out.println(isDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Date is in the wrong format.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `java.util.Calandar()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `split()` method :

```
 String []myformat=isDate.split(" ");
 System.out.println(myformat[2]);
 System.out.println(myformat[1]);
 System.out.println(myformat[3]);
 System.out.println(myformat[0]);
```

use order whatever order you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to tokenize this and print the 4 parts out on 4 separate
>   lines, starting with month, then date, then year, then day. What's the
>   best way to do this?

You have `Date` `Object` you should better use `Calendar` to get as specific details as possible without formatting your date.

***Note*** that problem with formatting and splitting is that in different format location of month, date and year will be different in `String`.

Which will not be the case in following code,

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

String month = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);
int date_ = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String day = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);

System.out.println(day);
System.out.println(date_);
System.out.println(month);
System.out.println(year);
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Tue
25
Aug
2015
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can solve your problem:

```
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(isDate, " ");
    Map<String, String> dateParts = new HashMap<String, String>();

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        dateParts.put("dayOfWeek", (String)tokenizer.nextElement());
        dateParts.put("dayNumber", (String)tokenizer.nextElement());
        dateParts.put("month", (String)tokenizer.nextElement());
        dateParts.put("year", (String)tokenizer.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("Month: "+dateParts.get("month"));
    System.out.println("Day of week: "+dateParts.get("dayOfWeek"));
    System.out.println("Date: "+dateParts.get("dayNumber"));
    System.out.println("Year: "+dateParts.get("year"));
```

Comment: Rustam's answer is more practical and easier. However this demonstrates how to use StringTokenizer to resolve your problem. May be you can find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.setTime(date);
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```